# Restore .classpath of a project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I have deleted `.classpath .project .settings` of a project in the project directory. I have refreshed that maven project in Eclipse. Lots of errors due to those files missing. I rebuilt the project. `.project  .settings` are created successfully. But not `.classpath` file. Same error exists. I have deleted project from eclipse workspace and tried the same. Still that file is missing.

Please help me to solve this issue

Right click option doesn't show me `configure build path` option

Comment: "I rebuilt the project." How?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Are you the downvoter? I can build it successfully in command line. But not in Eclipse.

Comment: I accidentally did this myself because I did a git clean not realizing that it would remove my local copies of .project etc.  good think is I just cloned my project again from git into a new folder and life is good again.  strongly recommend keeping your important projects backed up on a git repo

Answer (score 1):

Re-import the project in the Eclipse. It will automatically create .classpath file for a project.
I once had the same problem with Gradle project. I deleted the project from the workspace and re-imported the project and voila !! 
.classpath was created.